# Django model doesn't generate sql when the model name is similar to the filename?

Tags: sql, django

I'm writing an django app called **comments**, but sth. error when I use the model **Comment**.

I run following command and find that **Comment** doesn't generate sql.

```
python manage.py sqlall comments
```

part of output:

```
BEGIN;
CREATE TABLE "django_comments" (
    "id" integer NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
    "content_type_id" integer NOT NULL REFERENCES "django_content_type" ("id"),
    "object_pk" text NOT NULL,
    "site_id" integer NOT NULL REFERENCES "django_site" ("id"),
    "user_id" integer REFERENCES "auth_user" ("id"),
    "user_name" varchar(50) NOT NULL,
    "user_email" varchar(75) NOT NULL,
    "user_url" varchar(200) NOT NULL,
    "comment" text NOT NULL,
    "submit_date" datetime NOT NULL,
    "ip_address" char(15),
    "is_public" bool NOT NULL,
    "is_removed" bool NOT NULL
)
;
CREATE TABLE "django_comment_flags" (
    "id" integer NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
    "user_id" integer NOT NULL REFERENCES "auth_user" ("id"),
    "comment_id" integer NOT NULL REFERENCES "django_comments" ("id"),
    "flag" varchar(30) NOT NULL,
    "flag_date" datetime NOT NULL,
    UNIQUE ("user_id", "comment_id", "flag")
)
;
...

CREATE TABLE "comments_url" (
    "id" integer NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
    "content" varchar(64) NOT NULL,
    "url" varchar(2048) NOT NULL
)
;
CREATE TABLE "comments_commentboard" (
    "id" integer NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
    "title" varchar(64) NOT NULL,
    "url" varchar(2048) NOT NULL
)
;
CREATE INDEX "django_comments_37ef4eb4" ON "django_comments" ("content_type_id")
;
CREATE INDEX "django_comments_99732b5c" ON "django_comments" ("site_id");
CREATE INDEX "django_comments_6340c63c" ON "django_comments" ("user_id");
CREATE INDEX "django_comment_flags_6340c63c" ON "django_comment_flags" ("user_id
");
CREATE INDEX "django_comment_flags_3925f323" ON "django_comment_flags" ("comment
_id");
CREATE INDEX "django_comment_flags_9f00eb17" ON "django_comment_flags" ("flag");


COMMIT;
```

part of models.py:

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
import datetime

...

class Url(models.Model):
    content = models.CharField(max_length=64)
    url = models.URLField(max_length=2048)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.content

class Comment(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=64)
    comment_str = models.CharField(max_length=128)
    #desc = models.CharField(max_length=64)
    #comment_board = models.ForeignKey(CommentBoard)

    #def __unicode__(self):
    #    return self.title + ':' + self.content

class CommentBoard(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=64)
    url = models.URLField(max_length=2048)

    def __unicode(self):
        return self.title
```

When I rename Comment to Comment123, then it works. But I guess it's a limitation
I don't know before. Could anyone tell me why is it?

```
CREATE TABLE "comments_url" (
    "id" integer NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
    "content" varchar(64) NOT NULL,
    "url" varchar(2048) NOT NULL
)
;
CREATE TABLE "comments_comment123" (
    "id" integer NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
    "title" varchar(64) NOT NULL,
    "comment_str" varchar(128) NOT NULL
)
;
CREATE TABLE "comments_commentboard" (
    "id" integer NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
    "title" varchar(64) NOT NULL,
    "url" varchar(2048) NOT NULL
)
;
```

Should I not use **Comments** as app-name and **Comment** model at the same time?

Can anyone tell me where to find the limitation?

Comment: May be using the model name as same as an app name causes the problem

Comment: app-name: **comments** model-name: **comment** , they conflict?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It shouldn't matter if the model name is similar to the app name.

Apps in up your `INSTALLED_APPS` setting must be unique. If you have `'django.contrib.comments'` in your `INSTALLED_APPS`, then you can't name your app `comments`.